# Get the contents with the brackets using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am new to regular expressions. I am trying to get the contents within the brackets using regex

Examples

1. `7+(4*6)` ---> `(4*6)`
2. `(44/(2*( 1 + 3)))` ----> `( 1 + 3)`
3. `(54-(23+12))` ----> `(23+12)`

So, my expected output starts with `(` followed by digit followed by space(may be not) followed by any of the four operators (+,-,*,/) followed by space(may be not) followed by `)`.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\( *\d+ *[-+*/] *\d+ *\)
```

It means:

- Match the character "(" literally.
- Match the character " " literally.

  - Between 0 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match a single digit 0..9

  - Between 1 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match the character " " literally.

  - Between 0 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match a single character present in the list "-+*/".
- Match the character " " literally.

  - Between 0 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match a single digit 0..9

  - Between 1 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match the character " " literally.

  - Between 0 and unlimited times, as many as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- Match the character ")" literally.

Examples:

```
var regExp = /\( *\d+ *[-+*/] *\d+ *\)/;
"7+(4*6)".match(regExp)[0];            // "(4*6)"
"(44/(2*( 1 + 3)))".match(regExp)[0];  // "( 1 + 3)"
"(54-(23+12))".match(regExp)[0];       // "(23+12)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead to grab inner most parentheses and enclosed text.

This regex should work:

```
\((?=[^(]*$)[^)]*\)
```

**TESTING:**

```
'7+(4*6)'.match(/\((?=[^(]*$)[^)]*\)/);
//=> ["(4*6)"]

'(44/(2*( 1 + 3)))'.match(/\((?=[^(]*$)[^)]*\)/);
//=> ["( 1 + 3)"]

'(54-(23+12))'.match(/\((?=[^(]*$)[^)]*\)/);
//=> ["(23+12)"]
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/fQ2iZ2

Answer (score 0):

```
\.*(\([^()]*\))\.*
```

And your best [pal](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: What exactly does the code above do? How is it useful?

Comment: It is the regular expression you requested. It looks for the parenthesis without nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

try this variant

```
\((?!.*\().*?\)
```